# Filter data points on a map using R Leaflet and Shiny (multiple criteria)

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I am trying to create a filter map based on two categories "material" and "application". The user can select between 4 different materials and 4 different applications. Some data points have multiple values (i.e. "water,sand"). 
I am struggling with two issues:

1. Two points (id=2 and 3) appear on the map if I select application=c and material=sand instead of one point (id=3) only. I somehow have to check whether both filter criteria apply for each data point (id) separately but I cannot find information how to do this.
2. It depends on the order of checking the boxes if points are selected or not.

I will be very happy if anyone can give me some hints.

Here is my minimum example:

```
library(data.table)
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(leaflet)

mydat <- data.table( id=c(1,2,3,4),
                     londd=c(20, 38, 96, 32),
                     latdd=c(60, 56, 30, 31),
                     material=c("stone", "water,sand", "sand", "wood"),
                     application=c("a","b","c","d"))

#Set up ui
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(h5("", width=2),
               checkboxGroupInput(inputId="MatFlag",label=h4("Material"), 
                                  choices=setNames(object=c("stone","water","sand", "wood"),
                                                   nm=c("stone", "water", "sand", "wood")),
               ),
               checkboxGroupInput(inputId="AppFlag",label=h4("Application"), 
                                  choices=setNames(object=c("a","b","c","d"),
                                                   nm=c("a","b","c","d")),
               ),
               position="left"),

  #App mainPanel content and styles
  mainPanel(fluidRow(leafletOutput(outputId="lmap")))
))

#Set up server
server <- function(input, output){
  #Build leaflet map
  lmap <- leaflet(data=mydat)%>%
    addProviderTiles("Stamen.TonerLite", 
                     options =providerTileOptions(noWrap = TRUE)) %>%
    fitBounds(~min(londd), ~min(latdd), ~max(londd), ~max(latdd))

  #Filter data
  datFilt <- reactive({
    filterName <- ifelse(length(input$MatFlag) == 0, 'none', input$MatFlag)
    mydat[grepl(filterName,material) & input$AppFlag%in%application]
  })

  #Add markers based on selected flags
  observe({
    if(nrow(datFilt())==0) {
      print("Nothing selected")
      leafletProxy("lmap") %>%
      clearShapes()}
    else{ #print(paste0("Selected: ", unique(input$InFlags&input$InFlags2)))
      leafletProxy("lmap", data=datFilt()) %>% clearShapes() %>%
        addCircleMarkers(lng=~londd, lat=~latdd,
                         clusterOptions=markerClusterOptions(), weight=3,
                         color="#33CC33", opacity=1, fillColor="#FF9900", 
                         fillOpacity=0.8) %>% clearShapes()
    }
  })

  output$lmap <- renderLeaflet(lmap)
}

#Run app
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, a couple of issues here:

Grepl does not work the way you think it does - it cannot compare two vectors together like `%in%` does. You need to first concantenate using `|` (regex OR), and then use grepl. datFilt should be:

```
  datFilt <- reactive({
    MatSearch <- paste0(c('xxx',input$MatFlag),collapse = "|")
    MatSearch <- gsub(",","|",MatSearch)
    mydat[grepl(MatSearch,material) & application %in% input$AppFlag]
  })
```

The next issue is with clearShapes. First of all, there is no reason for the second `clearShapes()` call in addCircleMarkers. If `clearShapes()` worked as expected, this would actually just clear any map you created. However, there seems to be a bug in how clearShapes works with MarkerClusters - contrary to documentation it can't clear them. Using `clearMarkerClusters()` does work:

```
  observe({
    if(nrow(datFilt())==0) {
      print("Nothing selected")
      leafletProxy("lmap") %>%
        clearMarkerClusters()
    } else { #print(paste0("Selected: ", unique(input$InFlags&input$InFlags2)))
      print("Something Selected")
      leafletProxy("lmap", data=datFilt()) %>% 
        clearMarkerClusters() %>% 
        addCircleMarkers(lng=~londd, lat=~latdd,
                         clusterOptions=markerClusterOptions(), weight=3,
                         color="#33CC33", opacity=1, fillColor="#FF9900", 
                         fillOpacity=0.8)
    }
  })
```

Subbing this into your code allows for the double filtering you are looking for

Comment: Thank you very much, Chris! There is just one more thing I don´t understand completely. If I select just a material nothing happens, but if I select just an application the data point appears on the map. Is it possible that the point only appears if both criteria are met?

Comment: @ChMoe you are totally right - this is a bug in my code. If you change to `MatSearch <- paste0(c('xxx',input$MatFlag),collapse = "|")` it should work